# The component metadata for component sharepoint list source could not be upgraded

Tags: sharepoint, ssis

I am trying to execute an existing SSIS package there is an error displaying

```
Error   1   Validation error. Data Flow Task: Data Flow Task: The component metadata for "SharePoint List Source, clsid {874F7595-FB5F-40FF-96AF-FBFF8250E3EF}" could not be upgraded to the newer version of the component. The PerformUpgrade method failed.      OpenSA_VOR_Top20_CountryImport (1).dtsx 0   0
```

Comment: Are you using a task factory component in the SSIS package?

Comment: I have an SSIS 2008 package and put in SSIS 2012 am getting the above mentioned error.

Can you tell me the what are the steps to follow to resolve that, how to upgrade that SharePoint List Adapter

Comment: See if this link helps you out - http://sqlsrvintegrationsrv.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SharePoint%20List%20Adapters

Answer (score 0):

Have install sharePointListAdaptersSetup.msi   on system ?
refer following link

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/37ed1d72-4b58-466a-800f-b693409a3326/the-component-metadata-for-component-sharepoint-list-source-could-not-be-upgraded?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Comment: This is a borderline [link-only answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231). You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference.